# What method signature is appropiate returning a generic object?

Tags: java, generics

What should be the signature of a method that takes a generic object and returns another generic object, one that either is the same or a sub class of the original class? That is, if the method takes some generic class `A`, the returned object is guaranteed to be either `A` or `B` such that `B extends A` (directly or indirectly)?

The code below exemplifies what I'm trying to do, in the function `getList()`:

```
package com.company;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    private Main(){
         List<String> stringList = new GenericMessageListCreator.getList(StringGenericMessage.class);
    }

    private class GenericMessageListCreator() {
        public List<GenericMessage<T1>> getList(Class<T1 extends GenericMessage> clazz) {
            return new ArrayList<T1>();
        }
    }

    private class GenericMessage<T> {
        public GenericMessage(){};
        private T internalValue;

        public void setValue(T value) {
            this.internalValue = value;
        }

        public void echoValue() {
            System.out.println("I contain " + internalValue);
        }
    }

    private class StringMessage extends GenericMessage<String>{}
    private class IntegerMessage extends GenericMessage<Integer>{}
}
```

Example aside, in actuality I'm writing a registry of classes that are used for `Command`s in a command pattern. When I get an object by its class I want to fetch the appropriate `Command` and pass the object to it.

Comment: What's the point of returning a `GenericMessage<T>` instead of just a `T`?

Comment: In this example none. The real reason I wanted to use it is explained in the end of the question. A actually want to return something that processes a T object A command. I then want to pass the origional object into that command and do something with the result. Returning a List<T1> is fine. Also I just choose list as something convenient that already has a generic signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for this signature:

```
public <T1 extends GenericMessage> List<GenericMessage<T1>> getList(Class<T1> clazz) {
    return new ArrayList<T1>();
}
```

You'll find more info about generic methods [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html).

**EDIT**

Based on what I understand from your sample code, I would go for something like (I corrected some syntax errors in your code):

```
private class GenericMessageListCreator {
    public <U, V extends GenericMessage<U>> List<U> getList(Class<V> clazz){
        return new ArrayList<U>();
    }
}

private class GenericMessage<T> {
    public GenericMessage(){};
    private T internalValue;

    public void setValue(T value)
    {
        this.internalValue = value;
    }

    public void echoValue() {
        System.out.println("I contain " + internalValue);
    }
}

private class StringMessage extends GenericMessage<String>{}
private class IntegerMessage extends GenericMessage<Integer>{}
```

Thus, you'll be able to create a `List<String` from `StringMessage like this:

```
List<String> stringList = new GenericMessageListCreator().getList(StringMessage.class);
```

Comment: No need for the upper bound on `T1`.

Comment: I don't get that workinging correctly. I get in idea two errors. <T1 extends GenericMessage says "Unexpected token" Class<T1> says "Expression expected" I already looked at this page but couldn't get it working based on that information.

Comment: I based my answer on your code, but why do you return a `new ArrayList<T1>()` when your return type is `List<GenericMessage<T1>>`?

Comment: You have some syntax error in your code (for example, the parenthesis placed after `GenericMessageListCreator`, if you remove them you will not get the "Unexpected token" anymore).

Comment: why pass in `clazz` if it is not used?

Comment: Because Wes wants to generate a new list from his GenericMessage classes. U is constrained by V class (passed in parameters). You could do a simpler method, without V class, but I'm not sure it would fit OP needs (with the suggested answer, you can create new lists without any knowing of the GenericMessage class and the expected generic type of the returned list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not even sure which method you want to have this behavious on, but I've assuming it's `getList()`:

```
private class GenericMessageListCreator() {
    public <T extends GenericMessage<?>> List<T> getList(Class<T> clazz) {
        return new ArrayList<T>();
    }
}
```